# Generating binary variables in Pig

Tags: apache-pig

I am newbie to the world of Pig and I need to implement the following scenario.

problem:
    Input to pig script: Any arbitrary relation say as below table

```
    A   B   C
    a1  b1  c1
    a2  b2  c2  
    a1  b1  c3
```

we have to generate binary columns based on B,C so my output will look something like this.

```
output 

    A   B   C   B.b1    B.b2    C.c1    C.c2        C.c3
    a1  b1  c1  1        0       1       0       0
    a2  b2  c2  0        1       0       1       0
    a1  b1  c3  1        0       0       0       1
```

Can someone let me know how to achieve this in pig? i know this can be easily achieved using R script but my requirement is to achieve via PIG.

Your help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

**input**

```
a1      b1      c1
a2      b2      c2
a1      b1      c3
```

**PigScript:**

```
X = LOAD 'input' USING PigStorage() AS (A:chararray,B:chararray,C:chararray);
Y = FOREACH X GENERATE A,B,C,
                       ((B=='b1')?1:0) AS Bb1,
                       ((B=='b2')?1:0) AS Bb2,
                       ((C=='c1')?1:0) AS Cc1,
                       ((C=='c2')?1:0) AS Cc2,
                       ((C=='c3')?1:0) AS Cc3;
DUMP Y;
```

**Output:**

```
(a1,b1,c1,1,0,1,0,0)
(a2,b2,c2,0,1,0,1,0)
(a1,b1,c3,1,0,0,0,1)
```

Comment: in my case the values are dynamic ,i don't know what value will be there so the ternary operator wont fit in my usecase.

Comment: AFAIK dynamic values wont fit into pig. I am not sure is there any other way to solve this problem. If i find some solution definitely i will reply back.